# setVgap(0), setHgap(0) not working in gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I am trying to build an app that has some components such as buttons, labels, text fields, a menu bar and a picture (I didn't tackle the image problem yet so there is no code for that).

So I made a grid layout for my frame and constructed 6 panels with their respective components as explained in the code bellow. But when I run it it doesn't show anything at first, just a blank frame, unless I maximize the window.  Because when I do that everything appears to be working fine. Except for 2 things.

I have `setVgap()` and `setHgap()` to zero but there are still gaps between the components. and the 2nd thing is that the `BorderLayout.NORTH`, `(..).SOUTH` etc don't seem to work either.

```
public class Window extends JFrame {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private JPanel menupanel = new JPanel();

 public Window() {

    super("Image Application");

    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    requestFocus();

    // Setting Layout
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(6, 0, 0, 0);
    //grid.setVgap(0);
    //grid.setHgap(0);
    this.setLayout(grid);

    // Menu
    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("Options");
    JButton button = new JButton("Reset");

    // Buttons
    menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Left"));
    menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Center"));
    menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Right"));

    // Picture
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();

    // 2x JLabels and ComboBoxes to get the preferred dimensions
    JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel p3 = new JPanel();

    JLabel b2 = new JLabel("Width:  ");
    JLabel b3 = new JLabel("Height: ");

    JTextField box1 = new JTextField(25);
    JTextField box2 = new JTextField(25);

    // Resize Button
    JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
    JButton b4 = new JButton("Resize");

    // Adding Components to their panels
    p2.add(b2);
    p2.add(box1);
    p3.add(b3);
    p3.add(box2);
    p4.add(b4);
    menu.add(button);
    menubar.add(menu);

    // add all of the panels to JFrame
    this.add(menupanel);
    this.add(p1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(p2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.add(p3, BorderLayout.WEST);
    this.add(p4, BorderLayout.EAST);
    this.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Window w = new Window();

}
}
```

Any ideas?

~EDIT1 changed according to first 2 comments, the pack(); seems to fix the problem that i needed to maximise the window to see the comp's ( -Thanks ), but the setVgap() problem remains.

~EDIT2 when I run it this window is shown:
[image]

While I want it to look more like this:
[image]

*AGAIN Ignore the picture*

~EDIT3 Well, I changed the value that was passed in the constructor for the Hgap and it does change accordingly for different values but it seems that zero Hgap is still ~10 pixels wide?! Also I noted that the gap doesn't change between the menubar and the first Jbuttons, but only for the ret of the components.

~EDIT4 It also works for negative int's..?! I am lost here..

Comment: You can try an alternative solution's using its constructor [GridLayout(int rows,int cols,    int hgap,int vgap)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Comment: 1) `setVisible(true);` should be last. 2) `setSize(350, 350);` should be `pack()` and done after all components are added.

Comment: should be an answer, plus read an Initial Thread, logics for Layout Manager could be - JComponents returns its size to container

Comment: @mKorbel I'm sory but I didn't quite understand what you said (see edit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- please to compare, you should using second parameter for `GridLayout`, then `setVgap()` will works (`frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 0, 5, 5))`;), here is only zero value,
- Window is reserved word in Java for awt.Window, don't to use this Object name as class name

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MyWindow {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel menupanel = new JPanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image Application");

    public MyWindow() {
        // Menu
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Options");
        JButton button = new JButton("Reset");
        // Buttons
        menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Left"));
        menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Center"));
        menupanel.add(new JButton("Allign Right"));
        // Picture
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setBackground(Color.RED);
        // 2x JLabels and ComboBoxes to get the preferred dimensions
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        JLabel b2 = new JLabel("Width:  ");
        p2.add(b2);
        JTextField box1 = new JTextField(25);
        p2.add(box1);
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JLabel b3 = new JLabel("Height: ");
        JTextField box2 = new JTextField(25);
        p3.add(b3);
        p3.add(box2);
        // Resize Button
        JPanel p4 = new JPanel();
        p4.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        JButton b4 = new JButton("Resize");
        // Adding Components to their panels
        p4.add(b4);
        menu.add(button);
        menubar.add(menu);
        // add all of the panels to JFrame
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 0, 5, 5));        
        frame.add(menupanel);
        frame.add(p1);
        frame.add(p2);
        frame.add(p3);
        frame.add(p4);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyWindow w = new MyWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something like what you did, except I extended JFrame in the class.But I passed as args in the constructor width,height=0, as shown above, but it still doesn't work properly (see edit2)

Comment: Oh! i think I understand now the purpose of the added backgrounds thanks. but do you know of a way to make it look like the 2nd pic?

Comment: @Mechanic45: It looks like a `GridBagLayout` in `BorderLayout.SOUTH` to me, but you may want to pose a new question that focuses on the panel.